# NodeJS Gulp require is not defined

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I want to use system commands on my web application.
This is my Script

```
var gulp  = require('gulp')
var shell = require('gulp-shell')

gulp.task('example', function () {
 return gulp.src('*.js', {read: false})
   .pipe(shell([
     'echo <%= f(file.path) %>',
     'ls -l <%= file.path %>'
   ], {
   templateData: {
      f: function (s) {
        return s.replace(/$/, '.bak')
      }
    }
 }))
})
```

but i got

```
notice.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Comment: Are you running this in a browser? That's not going to work. Node.js is a server-side application.